# Watermark text in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

in my web application i am using javascript for water mark text in textboxes it is working fine but for textbox if TextMode property set to Multiline then the water mark text is not displaying is there any particular reason. this is my code...

```
<TextBox ID="txtone" runat="server" tooltip="Enter comments"
 onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter text,150 characters only';"
 onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter text,150 characters only') this.value='';" 
 value="Enter text,150 characters only">
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Probably because the CSS is built to affect input elements, not textareas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a `TextBox` is in multiline mode, it's rendered as a `textarea` instead of an `input` element. The `textarea` element doesn't use the `value` attribute, so your code fails to set the initial value.

Use the `Text` property of the server control instead of the `value` argument of the client control:

```
<TextBox ID="txtone" runat="server" tooltip="Enter comments"
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter text,150 characters only';"
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter text,150 characters only') this.value='';"
Text="Enter text,150 characters only"></TextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem Mr.Guffa it is working fine.